# Python URLs is showing an error, "The empty path didn't match any of these"

Tags: python, django

> Using the URLconf defined in todo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. ^admin/
> 2. ^todoapp/
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.

404 error is showing when I run my code which you can find below. This code is app url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from todoapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    #todoapp/1
    url(r'^(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

And it is the main url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^todoapp/',include('todoapp.urls')),
]
```

views.py is here:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Task
from django.template import loader


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('todoapp/index.html')
    context = {

            'task_list': task_list
    }
    return render(request, 'todoapp/index.html',context)

def detail(request, task_id):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    context = {
        'task': task,
    }
    return render(request,'todoapp/detail.html',context)
```

Why it is not working, I could not find a problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Okay. And what URL are you trying to access?

Comment: What URL are you typing in? Also, django has simplified the URL syntax, so you don't need as much regex. If you clarify what you're trying to do, there is likely a simpler code.

Comment: I was just tring to create a simple todo app for myself and fortunately I found my error I had not connected the url of the landing page thus it is showing me empty page error.